# What is an iPad app that will allow viewing AND editing/markup of PDF documents in multiple tab views?

Tags: ipad, pdf, tabs

I need to find an ipad app that will allow users to do the following:

1. View PDFs
2. Edit PDFs (at least simple markups)
3. Open multiple PDF documents in tabbed views
4. Link with a DropBox account for cloud access

Anybody know of an app to do this?

Adobe Acrobat Reader is just fine except the markup tools are week and only one doc at a time.  BlueBeam allows great editing and multiple tabs, but is super buggy and slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out **XODO**.

It seems it will cover all your needs. I’m using it since the first version.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Different! I've heard PDF Expert is an excellent app for editing PDFs. Goodreader, which you may already own is also highly recommended. Neither of these is free. You can read more about them on [this website](https://www.igeeksblog.com/best-pdf-editor-iphone-ipad-apps/).